# Issue posting data to api in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post

**I am trying to send data to my contact form api through react but I am getting this problem**

I tried to get input as a value to post through api when clicked on submit button but it is not working
error = the api should call like this [https://edu.orgiance.com/api/contactus?secret=xxxxx-ac40-46a0-9c81-d48a1322f4bb&fname=test&email=test@test.com&mobile=8463274946&message=test](https://edu.orgiance.com/api/contactus?secret=xxxx-46a0-9c81-d48a1322f4bb&fname=test&email=test@test.com&mobile=8463274946&message=test)

but it is calling like this
http://localhost:3000/?name=dfdfsd&email=dsffdsf%40gmail.com&phone=937285294&website=sxascsac&message=dscdscsfgcd#

My Code

```html
import React from 'react';

const ContactForm = (props) => {
const { submitBtnClass } = props;



function handleClick() {

    // Send data to the backend via POST
    fetch('https://edu.orgiance.com/api/contactus?secret=f1794e34-ac40-46a0-9c81-d48a1322f4bb&fname=test&email=test@test.com&mobile=8463274946&message=', {  // Enter your IP address here

      method: 'POST', 
      mode: 'cors', 
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonData) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header

    })
    
  }


  var jsonData = {
    "contact": [
        {
            "fname": props.fname,
            "email": props.email,
            "mobile": props.phone,
            "message": props.message
        }
    ]
  }

return (
    <form id="contact-form" action="#">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 mb-30">
                <input className="from-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={props.fname}  required />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-6 mb-30">
                <input className="from-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value={props.email} required />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-6 mb-30">
                <input className="from-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value={props.phone} required />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-6 mb-30">
                <input className="from-control" type="text" id="website" name="website" placeholder="Your Website" required />
            </div>

            <div className="col-12 mb-30">
                <textarea className="from-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message Here" value={props.message}></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="btn-part" >
            <button onClick={handleClick} className={submitBtnClass ? submitBtnClass : 'readon learn-more submit'}   type="submit">Submit Now </button>
        </div>
    </form>
);

}

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: All those _variables_ like `fname` are undefined

Comment: @Dave I tried to add value to input then fetch in  there but its not working

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating a functional stateless component. That means your data needs to be passed in the props object, and if you are trying to access it anywhere in the ContactForm component, you would need to use this format: props.*variablename* . ie:

```
<input className="from-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"  value={props.fname}required />
```

Comment: hey I added your changes and it worked but there is a problem as soon as I click on submit button it send post data to api like this http://localhost:3000/?name=dfdfsd&email=dsffdsf%40gmail.com&phone=937285294&website=sxascsac&message=dscdscsfgcd#.  but it should not be like this it should be like this https://edu.orgiance.com/api/contactus?secret=f1794e34-ac40-46a0-9c81-dxxxb&fname=test&email=test@test.com&mobile=8463274946&message=test

Comment: please read the above comment

Answer (score 1):

All of those variables are undefined. You can't initialize that jsonData object with variables that don't exist, you also can't set `<input value={undefinedVariable} ... />`

Since you are using form, an easy thing to do is to change it to look something like:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you can access the form data from the mouse event.

Example:

```html
function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const jsonData = {
      "fname": form.name,
      "email": form.email,
      "mobile": form.phone,
      "message": form.message
    };
    fetch('https://edu.orgiance.com/api/contactus?secret=f1794exxxxxx',
      method: 'POST', 
      mode: 'cors', 
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    })
}
```